# Backbone set parse dynamically

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

The Backbone documentation for [collections](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) shows example where you set parse when collection is defined.

```
var Tweets = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  // The Twitter Search API returns tweets under "results".
  parse: function(response) {
    return response.results;
  }
});
```

But, is there a way to set a function for parse after a Backbone collection has been instantiated?

```
this.collection.parse = function (response) {
    return response.results;
};

this.collection.fetch();
```

Comment: Did you try it? I'm pretty sure that'll work

Comment: You're right; I just tested it out and it works. Thanks!